# Invalid attempt to read data when reader is closed error

Tags: c#, winforms

On Form load, the code below runs fine. It runs the code in a method that runs on a timer (5 second interval).

I noticed that it will populate 2 rows before throwing an error in DataGridView.
Unsure why it throws "Invalid attempt to read when reader is closed error".

```
public void reloadDg()
{
  dg.Rows.Clear();
  dg.Refresh();

  try
  {
    TSID_POS = 0;
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", conn))
    {
      using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
          if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(0)) > TSID_POS)
          {
            TSID_POS = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(0));
          }
          PartInfo[0] = reader.GetString(0);
          PartInfo[1] = reader.GetString(1);
          PartInfo[2] = reader.GetString(2);
          PartInfo[3] = reader.GetString(3);
          PartInfo[4] = reader.GetString(4);
          PartInfo[5] = reader.GetString(5);
          PartInfo[6] = reader.GetString(6); 
          PartInfo[7] = reader.GetString(7);
          this.ListParts.Rows.Insert(0, reader.GetString(0),
                                        reader.GetString(1),
                                        reader.GetString(2),
                                        reader.GetString(3),
                                        reader.GetString(4),
                                        reader.GetString(5),
                                        reader.GetString(6),
                                        reader.GetString(7));
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
      }
      conn.Close();
      conn.Dispose();
      AR = 1;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you dont create the instance of `MySqlConnection` with a `using`-statement here, which is best practise for several reasons? It looks wrong that you dispose it here. Where you create a new connection then? You cannot use a disposed connection.

Comment: It isn't necessary to call `Dispose()` on things that are in a `using` statement.

Comment: You may upvote the accepted answer as well :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code block has been corrected as follows and it might be useful for you:

```
        try
        {
           .....

           using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
           {

            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", conn))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {                         

                        .....
                    }

                    reader.Close();                        
                }
                                    
                .....
            }

             conn.Close();
          }
        }
```

Comment: To steal @Amy's comment from above: "It isn't necessary to call Dispose() on things that are in a using statement."  Or `Close()`.  The using-block does that for you.